# Collapse blocks of assembly code?

Tags: assembly, sublimetext3

Lets say about this example code:

```
; comment
label_1:
    nop
.internal:
    ret

; comment
label_2:
    nop
    nop
    ret
```

Is there a way to make it look like below just on click at any label that ends with colon? (or somehow else)

```
; comment
label_1:

; comment
label_2:
```

Comment: Are you using an assembly language plugin?

Comment: @FrankC. only this https://packagecontrol.io/packages/NASM%20x86%20Assembly

Comment: OK, when you hover your mouse between the left border of "label_1:" the "collapse" control should appear.

Comment: @FrankC. Yes, It does not collapse the whole procedure but only from label to label :(